# Error in installing *install.packages("tstools")* in language R

Tags: r

I am getting some error while installing package **tstools**.
Several other packages were installed correctly like(xts, forecast, MAPA, openxslx),
but this one causing trouble.
R version: 3.5.0
RStudio version: 1.1.447
CRAN: Indonesia
OS: windows 10

Here is the error log...

**> install.packages("tstools")**
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/pc_name/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘data.table’
There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
binary  source needs_compilation
tstools  0.3.6 0.3.6.1    FALSE
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘data.table’
These will not be installed
installing the source package ‘tstools’
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tstools_0.3.6.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 960748 bytes (938 KB)
downloaded 938 KB
ERROR: dependency 'data.table' is not available for package 'tstools'
* removing 'C:/Users/pc_name/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/tstools'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘tstools’ had non-zero exit status
The downloaded source packages are in ‘C:\Users\pc_name\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6l4hr7\downloaded_packages’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using devtools?

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("trnnick/TStools")
```

Sometimes bioconductor also does the trick

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("tstools")
```

Comment: yeah... first one did the trick(devtools). Finally it installed. Can u explain about it

Comment: If the package is not on CRAN, then one can use devtools to install packages from github.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `install.packages("tstools", dependencies = T)` ?

Comment: it installed... but rolled back(remove) due to unavailability of **data.table**